# Is this addfront() function used with nalloc() for linked list wrong?

Tags: c, pointers

This code is taken from: page 20-21 of this [lecture notes pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-087-practical-programming-in-c-january-iap-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_087IAP10_lec06.pdf) from ocw.

```
 struct node∗ nalloc ( int data )
 { 
    struct node∗ p=( struct node ∗) malloc ( sizeof (node )) ; 
    if ( p!=NULL) {
        p−>data=data ;
        p−>next=NULL;
    }
    return p;
 }

struct node∗ addfront ( struct node∗ head , int data )
{ 
    struct node∗ p= nalloc (data ); 
    if ( p==NULL) return head ;
    p−>next=head;
    return p;
}
```

I think the code is wrong because the pointer p is local to nalloc() and using it in addfront() would yield undefined behavior. I have seen [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797250/pointer-valid-out-of-scope) and believe I am correct but can someone verify?

Comment: the pointer `p` in both functions refers to dynamically allocated memory. When you return from a function the **stack** gets destroyed. Dynamically allocated memory is on the **heap** and is valid even at the end of the function. So, this code is correct.

Comment: `p` is local and it will be destroyed once the program flow gets out of the function `nalloc` but the memory it allocated will exist even after nalloc (until `free`d) and the address of the memory (if) allocated in `nalloc` by `p` is valid.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: Quibble. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin For the missing header case, compiler issues a warning: `include '<stdlib.h>' or provide a declaration of 'malloc'`

Comment: What is it with so many people casting malloc?

Comment: @anastaciu So the code can be compiled with a C++ compiler too.

Comment: @Ayxan, I see, though the reason for that still puzles me.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus - the compiler will provide an implicit declaration of `mailloc`, but the implicit declaration will not be compatible with normal `malloc` (the implicit implementation will return type `int` -- the default in C)

Answer (score 1):

The function is right. But your logic is not so wrong. The variable `p` is effectively local and won't exist anymore when the function will return. However, `p` is not the memory you allocated with `malloc`, but a variable storing **the address of the memory** you allocated.

Thus, the statement `return p;` will return a copy of `p`, so a copy **of the address** of the memory you allocated using `malloc()`.

In the linked question, the user creates a local array and returns a pointer to it. See, the array is **local** and now dynamically allocated using `new` or `malloc()`. So his variable effectively contains the (automatically) allocated memory, and not the address of it. However, only the address is returned so the memory is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct. While `p` is a local variable on stack, what it points to isn't. What is happening is a pointer to a `node` on the heap is returned from `nalloc` and a copy of that pointer is used safely in `addfront`. The code is fine.

Comment: How is it different from the msg pointer in the linked question?

Comment: @Archer `msg` is s *static* array on the stack. It is destroyed when the function returns. `p` is pointing to *dynamically allocated* memory, which is fine to use until it is freed with `free()`.